# flutter: How to send multilingual notifications via firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

in my shopping app, the first thing the user does is to choose between three languages based on three buttons to operate the app with, english, arabic etc .. in the initState of my main page I can make an if statement like this:

```
if (chosenLanguage == "english") {
fcm.subscribeToTopic("messages");
}
else if (chosenLanguage == "arabic") {
fcm.subscribeToTopic("messagesArabic");
}
```

and so on..

however in my index.js to create automatic push notifications i only subbed the user to the "messages"(ie english) collection and idk how to make it sub to other topics(i.e  messagesArabic) based on the users choice. how to i write the sub to arabic and sub to english and other languages in my index.js?

here's the code for my cloud fucntions:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var newData;
exports.messageTrigger = functions.firestore.document('messages/{messagesId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
newData = snapshot.data();
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: newData.message,
        body: newData.body,
    },
        data: {
      click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
      message: newData.message,
    }
};
    admin.messaging().sendToTopic('messages', payload);
});
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to create additional payloads for those additional languages and then call `sendToTopic` for each of those. What's the problem you have implementing this?

Comment: thankyou, my question is do i have to make messageTriger for every one of the languages ?, because right now its only connected to one of my firebase collections which is the english language. i have another collection for sending the arabic notifications how do i write the code for that in my index.js to have both languages active and sent to the topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To subscribe to multiple collections you can have another parameter in the path that triggers the function:

```
exports.messageTrigger = functions.firestore.document('{languageId}/{messagesId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
```

Then you can use the `collectionId` parameter in the code to determine what language to send:

```
if (context.param.languageId == "english") {
  await admin.messaging().sendToTopic('messages', payload);
}
else if (context.param.languageId == "arabic") {
  await admin.messaging().sendToTopic('arabic', payload);
}
```

Note that you may want to put all push notification collections in a specific collection, as otherwise your code will trigger for writes to **any** collection even if one that have nothing to do with notification.

So for example:

```
exports.messageTrigger = functions.firestore.document('notifications/default/{languageId}/{messagesId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
```

So here `notifications` is the top-level directory where all notifications go, and `default` is a (likely the only) document in there). Under that you then have a collection for each language.

Comment: So you are saying that i make a collection named notifications then inside that collection have a default document, and in that document i'll have English collection and other language collections.. and I subscribe my users in my shopping app to the notifications collection? How do I subscribe the users to a specific language inside the notifications topic? I don't understand what you wrote clearly im sorry

Comment: Your users would subscribe to the topic for their language, just like you already have in your first code-snippet. It'd just be in your Cloud Functions code that you then determine the language for each message that is posted (with the `if` code I showed) and then send it to the right topic. I expanded that code in my answer a bit.

Comment: can you write me the full code please, i don't understand where to put the ifs and idk which exports to use

Comment: the chosenLanguage  is a variable inside my app it has nothing to do with firebase

Comment: @azheenI understand that you need to create 2 topics and if the customer change the language on your app you need to switch the subscribed topic.

The cloud function will be listen your collection, but each message must have the property "languageId" this property determine the message topic(language) and will be delivered to the users that were subscribed.

Comment: is that LanguageId a field name? is that what you mean by a parameter? @jahdzp

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please check my code here and tell me what i did wrong https://stackoverflow.com/q/62550957/12742251?stw=2  thankyou

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by making my functions index.js like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
 
var newData;
 
exports.messageTrigger = functions.firestore.document('notifications/{notificationsId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
newData = snapshot.data();
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: newData.message,
        body: newData.body,
    },
        data: {
      click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
      message: newData.message,
    }

};

if (newData.language === 'english'){
    await admin.messaging().sendToTopic('english', payload);
}else if (newData.language === 'arabic'){
await admin.messaging().sendToTopic('arabic', payload);
}
  
});
```